# Android: How to create ViewPager with spread image in landscape and half image of spread in portrait?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

All I want to do is a horizontal Pager in Android to **scroll magazine pages.**

**Landscape Mode :** Page-1 & Page-2 in single screen

**Portrait Mode :**  Page-1 in first screen and Page-2 in second screen. like wise..

If I have 10 screens in landscape then it'll be 20 screens in portrait.

I have looked many articles and tried HorizantalPager, HorizantalListView & ViewPager but none of them seem to be doing what I want.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?